# having trouble reloading partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

using rails 3.1, jquery v1.6.4, jquery-ujs

im trying to reload a partial but it doesnt seem to be working as desired:

```
<div id="album"> <%= render 'album_index' %></div>

<%=link_to 'Show All Albums', albums_path(:filter_by => 'all'), :remote => true%><br>
<%=link_to 'Show Old Albums', albums_path(:filter_by => 'old'), :remote => true%><br>
```

index.js.erb

```
$("#album").html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'album_index') %>');
```

when a user first loads 'index', <%= render 'album_index' %> will render properly with return ALL rows in my Album model be default. when a user clicks on the 'Show Old Albums' link, the jquery action will load 'album_index' with will run a specific query in my controller based on the param[:filter_by] == "old" and return the proper result that is passed back into the view.

now the problem is when i click on the link that loads the "old" filter, it doesnt reload the existing render but double renders it. So my view includes the render 'album_index' with the results from param[:filter_by] == "all" and below that 'album_index's renders again but with results from param[:filter_by] == "old".

i would for it not not double render but reload the existing partial with new results.

any suggestions?

Comment: I think there is a problem with the render 'album_index' part. It should be:

$("#album").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'album_index') %>");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using single quotes for the internal and external string in the second part of this:

```
$("#album").html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'album_index') %>');
```

This is causing the html to not be a proper string, which may be causing your issues. Use double quotes for the outter string as follows

```
$("#album").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'album_index') %>");
```